# Amazon AWS Amplify NestJs - host own frontend and backend

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nestjs

This is my first Question here.
I develop a fullstack nestJS app with Angular and want to host it on aws now. After i read the manual, they just always talk about "fullstack" in combination with multiple frontends.
The Backend Environment from AWS doesnt help me anything, because i wrote my own backend.

So, can someone tell me, who i can deploy frontend and backend on aws and connect them with a rds ?
Frontend works and i try something like that with the build file:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist/apps/frontend-app
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build-backend
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist/apps/api
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Thanks and stay healthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have custom applications you can deploy them classically on a virtual machine, in AWS it is, for example, an [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance. You can also deploy the dockerized applications on [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-docker-containers/)

You can connect your backend to a RDS via environment variables such as host, password, port... documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.html)